# Change pointers , Can call a function Module?

Tags: integration, abap

I need help with my task. I know the change pointer can generate an IDoc, but my task that when change happened. I want the change pointer to trigger it and call a Z program or function Module automatically (like how it generates the IDoc automatically), but in my case I need to call the FM.

The big picture: I need to connect SAP system with non-SAP system using webservice, and need that the changes that happened in SAP system to send to non-SAP system.
I need: change pointer >> call >> Zprogram / function Module >> content link>> webservice

Comment: `call >> Zprogram / function Module >> content link>> webservice` what is content link?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but it seems that you want to call a FM for an existing IDOC (the change pointers are already being created by a separate application), so that the FM can process the IDOC data and call the external webservice.
If that is the case, I think you can register an inbound function module for that, so that every time an IDOC is created, your FM can process it.
The documentation for that is here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/8f3819b0c24149b5959ab31070b64058/7.5.21/en-US/4a66ea4acbff260be10000000a42189b.html and is quite complete, and includes a coding example that may be useful.